# Why OLD Windows 10 cumulative updates can no longer be installed successfully?

Tags: windows-10, backup

On all my Win10 (version 20H2) computers I have the same problem - the last successfully installed cumulative update was 2021-04 (KB5001330). All newer cumulative updates failed and cannot be installed even manually when downloaded from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/).

I make backups of Windows using the AOMEI Backupper. So I tried to find an older backup that could be upgraded successfully, but I found **none**. Even when I return to the very first backup from year 2019 (Win10 version 17763/1809), I am unable to successfully install any **old** upgrade (e.g. version 1903 from 2019-10, KB4522355). All upgrades are either "Not applicable", or fail and are "undone". That's strange to me, as during its use, the computer was gradually successfully upgraded to version 20H2. Even when I let the computer upgrade automatically via Windows Update (it tries to upgrade directly to version 21H2), all version upgrades are rolled back.

**Question:** What's wrong? Why aren't the upgrade packages from Microsoft Upgrade Catalog usable?

In the Windows upgrade logs, there are only unhelpful messages (each upgrade produces different ones, and it's unclear to me which were fatal and which were ignored), like:

```
*FAILED* [8024000C] LoadHistoryEventFromRegistry completed
ResetPendingBlocks: Directory C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\0c730129a254f62f0eac46f025ad620b failed, 0x80070002
*FAILED* [8024000C] DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete
Failed to remove update E7AAA457-7E46-4A5B-BEE2-A5A740975BDB.1 from the in-use sandbox list
*FAILED* [80242000] Failed to initialize handler manager for cleanup operations
*FAILED* [80070032] Method failed [AppxPackage::Initialize:232]
*FAILED* [80070032] Method failed [AppxApplicabilityData::Initialize:549]
*FAILED* [80070032] EvaluateManifestBasedRule failed for update 743468BA-A535-48E1-B4EE-4859BD8DE51C.1, idExpr=57
*FAILED* [8024801E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpupdatehelper.cpp, line = 632
*FAILED* [80004004] {E54D748E-EAF0-497D-84D6-DF83FB96472D} [d:E64C3A45]: Job shutdown [CAppxRangeRequestJobNoBlockValidation::Run:1702]
ResetPendingBlocks: Directory C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ca4af4339884f7018bf988ecac7702ff failed, 0x80070002
*FAILED* [80248014] GetServiceObject couldn't find service '20851992-A1F4-440A-B5AB-3DCB2BCFFB27'.
*FAILED* [80246007] ISusInternal:: IsCommitRequired
*FAILED* [8007139F] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\handler\osdeployment\helper\osdeploymenthelper.cpp, line = 771
*FAILED* [8007139F] ISusInternal:: IsCommitRequired
...and other errors, but not all during the same upgrade...
```

and different GUIDs.

**Edit: Details:**
For instance, I have allowed automatic upgrade to 21H2 from version 19042/20H2. As any other upgrade, this one restarts the computer, fails at 98%, and then performs "undo" of the changes. SetupDiag then reports (in SetupDiagResults.log):

```
HostOSVersion = 10.0.18363
HostOSBuildString = 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.621 (vb_release_svc_prod1.201014-1758)
...
SetupDiag reports successful upgrade found.
This appears to be a successful update as the last operation was: OOBEBoot and the result was: success
```

Comment: `All upgrades are either "Not applicable"` - Can you give specific examples.  What is the exact build you are on?  Windows 10 20H2 hasn't been supported for nearly 6 months.  This is the reason you are having problems downloading cumulative updates for Windows 10 20H2.  I assume manually upgrading to Windows 10 21H2 isn't an option?    There is a tool called Setup Diag, which can determine the reason feature updates are failing to install.  *We need that log.* I assume you have tried the 21H2 upgrade assistant?

Comment: The error log you did provide, indicates, you receive 0x80070002.  The accepted advice at this point is to mount the ISO and perform an in-place upgrade allowing you to keep everything.  obviously instead of staying on an unsuported version of Windows 10 you should upgrade to Windows 10 21H2.

Comment: “am unable to successfully install any old upgrade (e.g. version 1903 from 2019-10, KB4522355)” - You cannot install a 1903 update if your running 1809 that is the reason you are getting a non-applicable message

Comment: @Ramhound Why I am not allowed to upgrade from 1809 to 1903?

Comment: @Ramhound Iwould like to upgrade to 21H2, but I am unable to. If this was a problem of a single home computer, I would throw the Windows away and installed the 21H2 version from scratch. But I have the same problem on all my computers, perhaps because they all are configured the same way. For a long time I was trying to find the reason why all Win upgrades fail with no success. Now I tried to return to a very old version, but I am unable to upgrade either - I tried various target versions, and was unable to install any of them.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried SetupDiag, but it has found no problem, see the details I added to my question.

Comment: I have found that after a version of Windows 10 becomes unsupported, it's very difficult to install cumulative updates, despite them being released depending if they the version is a LTS version or not.  "Why I am not allowed to upgrade from 1809 to 1903?" - They are unsupported.  You also cannot downgrade your version from 20H2.

Comment: @Ramhound That's very inconvenient. I cannot upgrade to 21H2 directly, and from what you says, I am unable to upgrade to 21H2 step by step through older versions, either. :-(((